# coverage status check failed in PR

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

I created file azurepipeline-coverage.yml for turn it off

is should be like that ? just add that file in the repo ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLP2o.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change the default settings of the code coverage experience for pull requests, you must include a configuration YAML file named azurepipelines-coverage.yml at the root of your repo. Set the desired values in this file and it will be used automatically the next time the pipeline runs.

For more information, you could refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops#configuring-coverage-settings